# CastContext.getSharedInstance(Context) is now deprecated

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast, android-cast-api

As the title says, `CastContext.getSharedInstance(Context)` is now deprecated:

> getSharedInstance(Context context): This method is deprecated. Use getSharedInstance(Context, Executor) instead to handle the exception when Cast SDK fails to load the internal Cast module.
> https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext

What would be the correct way to specify an Executor and return the CastContext?
I got it working like this but I wonder if this is the best way to do it:

```
CastContext
    .getSharedInstance(context, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    .addOnSuccessListener(castContext -> {
        //do something with castContext
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
        //throw exception
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good for retrieving `CastContext` asynchronously.

But, in the [official cast sample app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/99d3de47890c7c02650db45dda806b5255d27787/app-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/VideoBrowserActivity.kt#L92), they are retrieving `CastContext` synchronously by directly calling `getResult()` on the `getSharedInstance()` task.

```kt
val castExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this, castExecutor).result
```

Comment: Doing this might result in crash with "Task is not yet complete" as this is async job

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the correct way to use it. In Xamarin (C#) you would do it this way :

```cs
var instanceTask =  CastContext.GetSharedInstance(Application.Context, Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor());
var sharedInstance = await instanceTask as CastContext;

// do something with it
```

Answer (score 0):

We could simply use the executor service already used for other background processing instead of creating a brand new one:

```
CastContext.getSharedInstance(getApplicationContext(), Common.getBackgroundProcessor());
```